# React native redux debugging on a physical device

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

So I know how to check the redux store for react native while using a simulator but how do you use check the store when you are on a physical Android device? Obviously the window console log wont work for this. This problem has been bugging me for a long time now

Comment: You want to debug in Android or iOS?

Comment: Did you try googling your question first? There's a react native debugger application that does all this for you, and it doesn't need console logs. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Comment: I already have that debugger on my system. Cant get it run with the physical device

Comment: install debug build on the device, shake the device and then press debug js remotely.

Comment: I recommend https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a thorough [guide](https://medium.com/@tetsuyahasegawa/how-to-integrate-react-native-debugger-to-your-expo-react-native-project-db1d631fad02) on how to get [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) working with Expo app. May help!